# Empty functions in python library

Tags: python, python-3.x

in many libraries that I was using, there are functions that are basically not doing anything and have docstrings. How are they used then? I want to figure out somethings, but when I look up source code, there is nothing in it.

**How does it work?**, is this metaclass approach ? I want to know understand this, not solve runtime problem.

Example of this `class / functions`, not much in it...

```py
# fafreplay.py
# encoding: utf-8
# module fafreplay
# from /home/greg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fafreplay.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# by generator 1.147
""" Supreme Commander Forged Alliance replay parser """

# imports
import commands as commands # <module 'commands'>

# functions

def body_offset(replay, bytes=None, bytearray=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    body_offset(replay: Union[bytes, bytearray]) -> int

    Find the offset at which the body starts by parsing the header.
    Raises `ReplayReadError` if the header data is malformed.
    """
    return 0

def body_ticks(body, bytes=None, bytearray=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    body_ticks(body: Union[bytes, bytearray]) -> int

    Count the number of ticks in the replay body without checking for desyncs.
    Raises `ReplayReadError` if the body data is malformed.
    """
    return 0

# classes

class Parser(object):
    # no doc
    def parse(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        """ Parse a replay """
        pass

    def parse_body(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        """
        Parse a replay body. This implies that the header has already been parsed in order for
        `data` to be at the correct offset.
        """
        pass

    def parse_header(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        """ Parse a replay header """
        pass

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    @staticmethod # known case of __new__
    def __new__(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        """ Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature. """
        pass


class ReplayReadError(Exception):
    # no doc
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    __weakref__ = property(lambda self: object(), lambda self, v: None, lambda self: None)  # default
    """list of weak references to the object (if defined)"""



class ReplayDesyncedError(ReplayReadError):
    # no doc
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass


# variables with complex values

__all__ = [
    '__doc__',
    'Parser',
    'ReplayReadError',
    'ReplayDesyncedError',
    'body_offset',
    'body_ticks',
    'commands',
]

__loader__ = None # (!) real value is '<_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7f643cf3ed10>'

__spec__ = None # (!) real value is "ModuleSpec(name='fafreplay', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7f643cf3ed10>, origin='/home/greg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fafreplay.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so')"
```

library link: https://libraries.io/pypi/faf-replay-parser/0.4.0
`pip install faf-replay-parser==0.4.0`

I am using this library in my code:

```py
# my_file.py
from fafreplay import body_offset, body_ticks
ticks = body_ticks(data)
```

which results in error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greg/_Local/git/faf-replay-analyzer/src/replay_reader.py", line 39, in <module>
    ticks = body_ticks(data)
fafreplay.ReplayReadError: Invalid command!
```

Comment: Those are not the real function implementations, as you can tell. That is your IDE trying to be helpful to show you the function and class signatures and documentation. Those are likely C libraries.

Comment: This has nothing to do with metaclasses, as pointed out, these are just stubs made by your IDE

Comment: Thanks Cory, I will investigate sources than, I also had no idea python can run other files then `.py`

Comment: @GrzegorzKrug they are part of the CPython runtime, like the interpreter itself